# How to disable bitmap fonts?

Tags: fonts

I was trying a bitmap font from github, and I had to enable bitmap fonts as they are disabled by default in Ubuntu. I did not know that enabling bitmap fonts would have some *side-effects*. I'm sure something seems wrong with my the text in Chrome(just as if it's using a new font altogether). I don't like it. So I'd like to **revert** it as it was before I enabled bitmap fonts.

I used the following commands to enable bitmap fonts:

```
cd /etc/fonts/conf.d/
sudo rm /etc/fonts/conf.d/10* && sudo rm -rf 70-no-bitmaps.conf && sudo ln -s ../conf.avail/70-yes-bitmaps.conf
sudo dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig
```

Please help me to disable bitmap fonts. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good gracious! Does anyone know of a GUI front-end app for this stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directory `/etc/fonts/conf.d/` contains symbolic links to configuration files within `/etc/fonts/conf.avail/`.  These symlinks can be added and removed to customize the configuration of fontconfig.

The commands you previously ran disabled all `10-*` configuration options, as well as disabling `70-no-bitmaps` and enabling `70-yes-bitmaps`.  To reverse the latter part specifically, you can run the following:

```
cd /etc/fonts/conf.d
sudo rm 70-yes-bitmaps.conf
sudo ln -s ../conf.avail/70-no-bitmaps.conf ./
```

To reverse the effect of disabling the `10-*` configuration files depends on which config files you had enabled to begin with.  Here are the `10-*` config files I have enabled on my machine:

```
cd /etc/fonts/conf.d
sudo ln -s ../conf.avail/10-hinting-slight.conf ./
sudo ln -s ../conf.avail/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf ./
sudo ln -s ../conf.avail/10-sub-pixel-rgb.conf ./
```

Alternatively, here is how you can enable the default `10-*` options for Ubuntu Bionic:

```
cd /etc/fonts/conf.d
sudo ln -s ../conf.avail/10-hinting-slight.conf ./
sudo ln -s ../conf.avail/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf ./
sudo ln -s ../conf.avail/10-antialias.conf ./
```

I would personally recommend however, that you opt for `sub-pixel-rgb` instead of `antialias` unless you don't have a standard LCD monitor.

You may find however that the strange font rendering you're getting in Chrome is because you disabled these `10-*` config files and not because you enabled bitmap fonts.  You may want to try only re-enabling just these config files without swapping back from `70-yes-bitmaps` to `70-no-bitmaps` before reverting completely to having no bitmap fonts.  Enabling `70-yes-bitmaps` should not affect any other fonts besides allowing bitmap fonts to be used.  It is also possible that you have some missing fonts and may get better results than you had originally by running:

```
sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Finally, after you have altered your fontconfig configuration, you should run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig
```

This will update your fontconfig cache so your changes can take effect.  You may also need to restart your programs / log out and back in / reboot your computer to see the changes take effect.

Comment: It seems that I already have `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` installed.  I also have no idea which `10-*` configuration files I had symlinked. Although, I can give you a list of of `10-*` config files in `/etc/fonts/conf.avail`:
edit in progress

Comment: @swingcake I have updated the answer with the defaults for Ubuntu.  You could enable these or instead opt for config files I have enabled if you would rather have subpixel "cleartype"-like font rendering.

Comment: Thank you for the very insightful answer. I have an IPS LCD panel, and would definitely follow your recommendation regarding that. I would also like to ask for the source of your information(the default `10-*` config files in Bionic). Another doubt I have is that why did the author of that particular bitmap font add the disabling of `10-*` config files if that was not required to enable bitmap fonts at all. Is there a relation at all between them? One more thing, in the command above to enable bitmap fonts `sudo ln -s ../conf.avail/70-yes-bitmaps.conf` there is no `./` compared to your command

Comment: Sorry, the above comment reached it's limit. I know that `./` means the current directory, but does this imply that there is no neccessity to mention that? (I mean, is it implied by default if the argument is missing as in the case above which I used to enable bitmap fonts?)

Comment: @swingcake I got the default files for Bionic by downloading the `.deb` package for `fontconfig-config` and inspecting its contents.  I'm not sure why they might remove the `10-*` configs.  Maybe they were intending to make all fonts non-antialiased.  I used `./` to be explicit about creating the symlink in the current directory (just what I'm used to and more similar to usage of the `cp` command), though it can be omitted and `ln` creates a symlink in the current directory by default.

Comment: Does leaving the bitmap font enabled have any effect on other fonts? (Just talking about `70-yes-bitmaps.conf`) The chrome text is back to normal as you said, by the way.

Comment: @swingcake Updated the answer (no it won't affect other fonts).

Comment: Cannot thank you enough, I'm going to accept your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Aside [answer by @Candy Gumdrop](https://askubuntu.com/a/1039801/469295), it's good to disable `embedded bitmap`, some fonts (like Calibri) will look terrible in some resolutions (see image bellow) if this setting stills enabled. Calibri fonts and other cleartype fonts have bitmap versions embedded in them which activate at small sizes, which makes it look bad.

You can disable by doing this:

```
cd /etc/fonts/conf.d

cat << END | sudo tee ../conf.avail/99-no-embeddedbitmap.conf
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <description>Disable embedded bitmap</description>
  <match target="font" >
    <edit name="embeddedbitmap" mode="assign">
        <bool>false</bool>
    </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
END

sudo ln -s ../conf.avail/99-no-embeddedbitmap.conf ./

sudo dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig
```

[image]

Comment: I can not up vote this enough! I had the exact same problem. Most probably after installing ttf-mscorefonts-installer which provides some fonts with embedded bitmaps. This helped instantly. No mangled "ti" etc anymore.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <match target="font" >
    <edit name="embeddedbitmap" mode="assign">
        <bool>false</bool>
    </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>

Is sufficient though. The rest throws warning and errors...

Comment: the 'its' tag is just to avoid translation of description by any software that may configure system's font. It's optional. @Bim -- see https://www.w3.org/TR/its20/ if you want to go deep in this subject

Comment: FontConfig also warns about the description tag not being supported. Im using Ubuntu 18.04.2 here.

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer now @Bim

Comment: this snippet can also be added to ~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf (Ubuntu 20.10) which has the benefit of keeping the change in the home directory, so it may survive Ubuntu upgrades better. Note that you may need to make the directory ~/.config/fontconfig

Answer (score 1):

Without sudo-privileges it can be done:

- create folder and file ~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
 <match target="font">
  <edit name="embeddedbitmap" mode="assign">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
</fontconfig>
```

---

alternatively the same as terminal-command:

```bsh
mkdir -p ~/.config/fontconfig/
cd ~/.config/fontconfig/
touch ~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf
echo '<fontconfig><match target="font"><edit name="embeddedbitmap" mode="assign"><bool>false</bool></edit></match></fontconfig>' >> fonts.conf
```

---

More infos: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1961136#p1961136

Comment: Just a heads up: you may already have a fonts.conf file and simply appending the whole XML wouldn't work. I had to insert the <match> block manually.