# How can I activate bitmap fonts on 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, fonts

I am using Ubuntu Mate 20.04. I want to use the Fixed 6x13 font in the terminal (not xterm). When I try to change the terminal font, the Fixed fonts are not in the list of available fonts. However, `mate-font-viewer` and and `xfontsel` show the Fixed fonts.

I followed the instructions how to enable this font in [How can I activate bitmap fonts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90001/how-can-i-activate-bitmap-fonts/1077643) and https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1270870. None of the provided solutions seems to work. This is what I did so far:

- I installed the `xfonts-100dpi` and `xfonts-75dpi` packages.
- In `/etc/fonts/conf.d/` I deleted `70-no-bitmaps.conf` and added the `70-yes-bitmaps.conf` or `70-force-bitmaps.conf` symbolic link. I tried both, one at a time.
- Following the instructions on https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1270870 I specifically enabled the `Fixed` font family by adding a `69-fixed-bitmaps.conf`.
- On every trial I ran `dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig-config`, `dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig` and `fc-cache -f` and rebooted my system.

How can I use these fonts on Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 6):

(see below for 24.04 Wayland update)

**Ubuntu 20.04** requires bitmap fonts to be manually enabled, and the bitmap font file must be in the [OpenType Bitmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenType) (otb) format.

Enable bitmap fonts:

```
$ rm /etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf
$ ln -s ../conf.avail/70-force-bitmaps.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/
$ dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig-config
$ dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig
$ fc-list | grep Fixed | grep 6x13.pcf
/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/6x13.pcf.gz: Fixed:style=SemiCondensed
/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/trad--6x13.pcf.gz: Fixed:style=SemiCondensed
```

If you do not have an otb font, then it is necessary to convert from a bdf font (conversion from a pcf font will result in incorrect sizing). This conversion can be done using `fonttosfnt`. Unfortunately the version of `fonttosfnt` in Ubuntu 20.04.1 is buggy and outputs fonts with incorrect spacing (see [1](https://bugs.gentoo.org/728308), [2](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/fonttosfnt/-/merge_requests/7)), so use of the latest git code is necessary.

Install latest fonttosfnt from git:

```
$ git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/fonttosfnt.git
$ apt-get build-dep xfonts-utils libfreetype6-dev libfontconfig1-dev xclip libfontenc-dev x11proto-core-dev
$ cd fonttosfnt
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
```

Download 6x13.bdf, rename to avoid collision with .pcf font, and convert to otb
format:

```
wget https://opensource.apple.com/source/X11fonts/X11fonts-14/font-misc-misc/font-misc-misc-1.1.2/6x13.bdf
sed -i 's/FAMILY_NAME.*/FAMILY_NAME "MyFixed"/' 6x13.bdf
./fonttosfnt -b -c -g 2 -m 2 -o myfixed.otb 6x13.bdf
```

Install new otb font:

```
$ cp myfixed.otb /usr/local/share/fonts
$ dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig-config
$ dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig
$ fc-list | grep otb
/usr/local/share/fonts/myfixed.otb: MyFixed:style=SemiCondensed
```

Start app, choose font, search for "myfixed".

**Ubuntu 24.04 (Wayland) update:**

The good news is that this still works, and some of the steps are simpler. The bad news is that the system `6x13` font still hasn't been updated to otb, and the `fonttosfnt` hasn't been upgraded either, so we still have to build the github code and manually convert the bdf font:

```
$ sudo cat > /etc/fonts/conf.d/70-force-bitmaps.conf << EOF
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
<!-- Accept bitmap fonts -->
 <selectfont>
  <acceptfont>
   <pattern>
     <patelt name="scalable"><bool>false</bool></patelt>
   </pattern>
  </acceptfont>
 </selectfont>
</fontconfig>
EOF
$ fc-list | grep Fixed | grep 6x13.pcf
/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/6x13.pcf.gz: Misc Fixed:style=SemiCondensed
$ git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/fonttosfnt.git
$ sudo apt-get build-dep xfonts-utils
$ cd fonttosfnt
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
$ wget https://opensource.apple.com/source/X11fonts/X11fonts-14/font-misc-misc/font-misc-misc-1.1.2/6x13.bdf
$ sed -i 's/FAMILY_NAME.*/FAMILY_NAME "MyFixed"/' 6x13.bdf
$ ./fonttosfnt -b -c -g 2 -m 2 -o myfixed.otb 6x13.bdf
$ sudo cp myfixed.otb /usr/local/share/fonts
$ fc-list | grep otb
/usr/local/share/fonts/myfixed.otb: MyFixed:style=SemiCondensed
```

Answer (score 4):

UPD: as in 22.04 there is a package fonts-terminus-otb, so one needs  only to remove `/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf` and restart X.

Original answer:

Menawhile Ubuntu has dropped support for bitmap terminus fonts included in the disto, I have used otb bitmap fonts from ArcLinux.
The original receipe from here: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/howto-use-terminus-bitmap-font-with-pango-1-44/101442

Here is its adaptation for Ubuntu 20.04:

1. Get the otb fonts package from https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/terminus-font-otb/ (Download From Mirror link)
2. Convert the package to .deb with alien:

```
    zstd -d terminus-font-otb-4.48-3-any.pkg.tar.zst
    fakeroot alien terminus-font-otb-4.48-3-any.pkg.tar
```

3. Remove /etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf
4. Install the resulting deb:

```
    sudo dpkg -i terminus-font-otb_4.48-2_all.deb
```

4. Logout-login (or restart X otherwise)

Viola! Beautiful terminus fonts available again!

Answer (score 2):

The newer 4.49 version of Terminus fonts includes OTB font installer. This works with the new `libpango` that dropped the older bitmap font support. Make sure you remove the distro-installed packages of Terminus and then do the following:

```
tar xzf terminus-font-4.49.1.tar.gz
cd terminus-font-4.49.1
make otb
sudo make install-otb
sudo cp 75-yes-terminus.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/
sudo dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig
```

The font should be available immediately and terminal restart is not necessary. Verified with 8x16 font (size=11) in `mate-terminal`, works as in good old 18.04. I am actually very satisfied, because the TTF replacement of Terminus was pretty bad.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me. Are there any non monospaced fonts that are bitmaps, that I could use for Ubuntu  UI?

Answer (score 1):

According to this https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/BitmapFontConversion there is no longer support for bitmap fonts in the old format. I tried to follow the method on that page but it did not work for me.

In the end I managed to convert and use the font I wanted by doing the following steps:

1. Opened it in fontforge (`/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/6x13-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz`)
2. Editing the font info (Element -> Font Info), changing the name and family so it does not clash with the bitmap font.
3. Saving it in otb-format (File->Generate Fonts...) to `~/.fonts`.
4. Then adding a new file in `/etc/fonts/font.d` with my new font family name.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

```
apt install fonts-terminus-otb
```

Works for me in the gvim.
Part of .gvimrc

```
set gfn=Terminus\ Medium\ 13
```

It doesn't work in gnome terminal for unknown reasons.