# Seeking bitmap font id for installation in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, fonts

I had been using a specific bitmap font (see image in following link) since Ubuntu 10.04, enabled via [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20090322134457/www.ubuntutips.net/node/14) technique, which worked until 18.04. The font would show up in gnome-terminal settings as "Fixed".
[My desired bitmap font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkecu.png)

I have now upgraded to 20.04, and the font is no longer available. I have verified that the technique in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1281443/637717) answer works to restore bitmap fonts on 20.04; however, I am seeking identification of the specific font I had been using so far. What bdf file corresponds to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it; turns out it is 9x15.bdf. I just downloaded them all and checked them one by one. Documenting steps here in case anyone else has an OCD itch to scratch:

1. wget with wildcards, from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/566206)

   `$ wget -r -nd -np -A '*.bdf' https://opensource.apple.com/source/X11fonts/X11fonts-14/font-misc-misc/font-misc-misc-1.1.2`
2. Script to check each bdf (wait for keypress from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/134444)):

   `$ for font in *.bdf; do echo $font; gnome-font-viewer $font & read -n1 -s -r -p $'Press key to continue...\n' key; done`

Find the font you want; then install via the technique in the previously-linked answer.